# Copy and rename file following a pattern with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a file with name like this:

> KE1_F00177_077_00_50

When I show the Property of the file, 2018.02.21.10.30 is the modified Date of the File which is copied like the picture below. I want to copy this file to another Location and rename it with Powershell. The new name should be:

> _F00177_2018_02_2018.02.21.10.30_KE1_F00177_077_00_50

[image]

Comment: I suggest you do some research work before asking. There are plenty of examples available on Internet for the problem you stated. See [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/b9c23f87-ce7a-4661-9c19-9ad5a16a271e/powershell-rename-files-in-folders-and-subfolders-to-date-and-time-stamp?forum=ITCG) and [this](https://rcbpowershell.wordpress.com/2013/09/05/rename-file-with-timestamp/).

Comment: i don't know how to extract the modified Date from the Property

Answer (score 0):

This will generate the format you mention including hour in 12 hour format (AM/PM).

```
$source = 'c:\temp\KE1_F00177_077_00_50'
$destinationFolder = 'c:\temp\new'
$file = Get-ChildItem $source
$date = '{0:yyyy_MM_yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm}' -f $file.LastWriteTime
$head = $file.Name.Split('_')[1]
Copy-Item  $source "$($destinationFolder)/_$($head)_$($date)_$($file.Name)"
```

However you should consider either using 24 hour format or including AM/PM in the name, otherwise it won't be easy to know when it is AM or PM.

For 24 hour format, replace `hh` for `HH`:

```
$date = '{0:yyyy_MM_yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm}' -f $modified
```